# Flask appropriate response for POST without template?

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

So I have a method for creating new exercises in the database for a workout app. I'm using angular to handle the ajax.

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def create():
    data = request.get_json(request.data)
    ex = Exercise(data['exName'], data['exType'])
    db.session.add(ex)
    db.session.commit()
```

After successfully committing, what is the best response to send back? I don't really need a success message, just need to let client know that it was successfully created. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should send 201 status([look here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)) Not 204 because you've just created new entity. And if you are trying to build good RESTful API you need to send 201 with the object you've created before.

And later, at the angular side, you can do what you want. You'll let users know about created exercise there.

Comment: Wow can't believe this got another answer! But yes, this is better. Just be careful that the object sent back doesn't have data we should hide, and that a meaningful return value is given for failures.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can send back HTTP 204 which is described by [w3.org rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

```
10.2.5 204 No Content

The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to 
return an entity-body, and might want to return updated 
metainformation. The response MAY include new or updated 
metainformation in the form of entity-headers, which if 
present SHOULD be associated with the requested variant.
```

I think you could do this in the end of your function

```
return '', 204
```

Comment: as a side note, parentness can be omitted, too.

Comment: Great! Thanks... That `204` did the magic and no page refresh as I wanted.